# Plotting a function in another .m file

Tags: matlab, plot

i started programming Matlab the last week and i`ve been trying to plot a function file with no success.

This is my function file (impuls.m). It basicaly should set y = 0 for 0<=x<5 and x>10. y = 5 for  5<=x<=10).

```
function y = impuls(x)

    if ((x>=0 && x<5) || x>10)
        y=0;
    else if (x>=5 && x<=10)
            y=5;
        end
    end

end
```

I guess i did it right, because when i test it on my main file (fourierreihe.m) using impuls(1) i get a "0" and when using impuls(7) i get a 5. The problem is when i try to get all resuts for the interval [0 13] and plot them as a rectangular impuls.

I tried using:

```
impuls([0 13])
```

But i keep getting the error:

```
fouhierreihen
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in impuls (line 3)
    if ((x>=0 && x<5) || x>10)

Error in fouhierreihen (line 1)
impuls([0 13])
```

Shouldnt i be getting something as "ans = 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 0" this as an answer?

So guys, what am i doing wrong? I`ve searched for videos and posts and i cant find the mistake there. How could i possibly plot it for the interval?

Thank you in advance,
Pedro.

Comment: `[0 13]` is not a range, `[0:13]` is a range. Neither one is a *scalar*, which the [short circuiting logical operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) require, as the error message and documentation both point out. You need to use [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true#bq7egb6-1) or [iterate through your values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html).

Comment: First thanks for answering. Even if is not a range, shouldnt it be giving me the answer for impuls(0) and impuls(13)? And i am pretty sure the function file is right. We`ve done the same exercice last week and it worked like this. I just cant remember how to work it with the main file to plot the function.

Comment: No, it shouldn't, for the reason I explained in my previous comment. `&&` and `||` must be passed scalars and neither `[0 13]` nor `[0:13]` are scalars. If you had this working for arrays then either `impuls` was written differently or you were calling it in a loop externally..

Comment: So. I changed NOTHING on the `impuls.m` file and it works now. Just had to use `fplot(@impuls,[0 13])` on the main file to plot my function in the interval 0 to 13. Why that? Thanks again.

Comment: Because `fplot` reverts to calling the input function for each element of the input interval (e.g. a loop) when array inputs fail. It should be giving you a warning stating this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message and [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) explain, inputs to the short-circuit logical operators must be scalars. It doesn't really make sense fundamentally trying to robustly short circuit with two arrays of truth values.

You can use [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true#bq7egb6-1) to accomplish the same task in a vectorized manner. For example:

```
function y = impuls(x)
y = zeros(size(x));  % Initialize the output array
y(x>=5 & x<=10) = 5; % Condition one
```

Which returns:

```
impuls(1) =

     0


impuls(7) =

     5


impuls([0 13]) =

     0     0


impuls(0:13) =

     0     0     0     0     0     5     5     5     5     5     5     0     0     0
```

---

That your original function works with [`fplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) is a concession from MATLAB's developers. The function documentation repeatedly states that the function being plotted must accept vector inputs (though they don't actually enforce it, apparently):

> The function must accept a vector input argument and return a vector
>   output argument of the same size

Your function doesn't do this, because `&&` and `||` are scalar operations. However, `fplot` will revert to calculating function outputs element-by-element (a loop) in the event that the array input fails, throwing the following warning:

```
Warning: Function fails on array inputs. Use element-wise operators to increase speed. 
> In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine>getFunction
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/updateFunction
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/set.Function_I
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/set.Function
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine
  In fplot>singleFplot (line 223)
  In fplot>@(f)singleFplot(cax,{f},limits,extraOpts,args) (line 182)
  In fplot>vectorizeFplot (line 182)
  In fplot (line 153)
  In trialcode (line 1)
```

Comment: I guess the professor didnt care much about the warnings. Hehe. But thanks for your answer, i got it now! I just wonder how i would do it your way if the function were any more complex, like y = 3x^(4-x) for 0<=x<=10 for exemple. Would you use a for loop from 0 to 10 to calculate it and asssing each result to its place in the array?

Comment: You could, but those are all matrix operations so it will generally be much faster to treat them as such: `x = 1:10; y = 3*x.^(4-x)`. Always try to code to the [language's strengths](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/language-fundamentals.html).

Answer (score 0):

My Friend....

Try this:

```
function y = impulse(t)
if 0
    %% Example
    t=(0:100)';
    y=impulse(t)
    plot(t,y);
end
for i=1:length(t)
    if ((t(i)>=0 && t(i)<5) || t(i)>10)
        y(i,1)=0;
    else if (t(i)>=5 && t(i)<=10)
            y(i,1)=5;
        end
    end
end
```

Note:

- the `for` loop is critical in these cases,
- the function `impulse` could exist anywhere, but your local version prevail,
- the `y(i,1)` retain your vector as columns,
- run the section inside the void loop (`if 0`)
- the time is normally used here as variable :)....

hyp.